# Cleaning a signal and computing period

Tags: signal-processing, periodic-functions

I am working with a signal which is a periodic square signal with some kind of noise and some outliers. I would like to know which is the best solution in order to get the period and clean the outliers that can be seen in the image:

[image]

The final goal is to binarize the signal.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should not ask the same question on two different stackexchanges. Please contact the moderators (click on the link marked `flag` at the bottom of your post) and ask them to migrate this question to dsp.SE which is a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

1. Lowpass filter the signal to remove the high-frequency noise.
2. Once you lowpass filter the original signal, it won't look like a square wave anymore. The infinitely sharp transitions will be damped. Thus, apply a $1$-bit quantizer (with hysteresis) to the output of the lowpass filter, so that you "binarize" the lowpass filtered signal.
3. Differentiate the "binarized" signal, in order to obtain a train of impulses. Compute the duration of the time intervals between successive impulses, compile a list of such durations, then compute a histogram, normalize the histogram, and then compute the 1st moment of the normalized histogram (which is an estimate of the expected value of the period).

Comment: Dear Rod, I fully understand your answer and I guess it will work well. I will try it immediately. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: A median filter (instead of an average) could be better for step 1.

Comment: @leonbloy: It's hard to implement a median filter using analog electronics, though.

Comment: @RodCarvalho Sure - it's also hard to compute histograms. But I don't see  anything about analog electronics in the OP.

Comment: @leonbloy: You're right. The solution I proposed is arguably ugly, but implementable using analog electronics. It's how digital signals are regenerated (if I remember my communication systems classes properly).